# sql - single table query vs. normalisation

Tags: mysql

Consider these tables:

**messages**

```
+-----------+------------+----------+----------------+
| messageId | fromUserId | toUserId | messageContent |
+-----------+------------+----------+----------------+
| 1         | 1          | 2        | Hello          |
+-----------+------------+----------+----------------+
```

**users**

```
+--------+----------+
| userId | userName |
+--------+----------+
| 1      | magnus   |
| 2      | fabiano  |
+--------+----------+
```

But when I have to display any message, I will need the `userName`, along with the message attributes.

What is the optimum approach:

1. Add a column `userName` to **messages** ? (one-table query, but compromise normalisation)
2. Keep it normalised as above (and have a two-table query)

Thanks.

Comment: Which `userName` should be considered when displaying the message, the `fromUser` or the `toUser`?

Comment: @chridam ... it is the one related to `fromUserId` ... but really, it is irrelevant. The question is related to the design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For most purposes you should keep it normalized and join the tables together in your query, and possible you could make a view that does the join for you so you only have to query the view.
Having the normalized approach will likely save you problems updating/maintaining data in the long run

Generally speaking, it's only when you start working with large databases and/or business intelligence you should worry about denormalizing for the sake of performance, because then there can be a intolerable overhead in the joins, compared to the difficulty and space usage of denormalizing.

Answer (score 0):

Have a two table query.  You have two entirely different entities -- users and messages.  One attribute of users is their "name".  They can have lots of other attributes, such as when the user was created, real names, aliases, and so on.

MySQL can handle the joins just fine, although you will probably need to learn a bit about indexing.

Answer (score 0):

I think as you have to use two tables because otherwise lot of values will be repeated in message table(redundancy). You will want a user_id because two users can have the same name.If you are going to remove users table you can have a unique identity to user

Answer (score 0):

Both (ish)

Add a view that shows the un-normalised data

e.g.

```
CREATE VIEW MessageDetails AS
SELECT f.userName AS fromUser,
       t.userName AS toUser,
       m.content AS content
FROM messages AS m
JOIN users AS f ON m.fromUserId = f.userId
JOIN users AS t ON m.toUserId = t.userId
```

Answer (score 0):

### ***Strictly TWO***

As this is message history table, I believe after few days it would be huge. Duplicating username just for display will be totally wrong as this would take un-necessary space.

Also think if user update his name, then you would again need to update this table just for those thousands/ lakhs rows for just one user.

Regarding display of name, even I will not join table. I will get name in separate query and in programming I will use that variable to show in chat.